# How to invoke feature tests from command in Laravel/Sail

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-sail

I have a command to generate documentation but it depends on caching some data from our feature tests. I can run feature tests simply with this command:

```
sail test --filter Feature
```

When I try to invoke this from inside my command:

```
sail apidocs:create
```

I invoke the tests like this:

```
$this->call('test', ['--filter' => 'Feature']);
```

But this method seems to ignore the switch and runs all tests, which is not what I want. It seems like I must be missing something elementary, but so far none of my tinkering has produced the desired result. Any ideas?

Comment: Try `sail test --filter ./tests/Feature`

Comment: @matiaslauriti I can do it fine from the command line. I meant using the call() method. That's where it ignores the --filter switch.